# Meteor mongodb saves number as 'NaN'

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm using the following method to add tasks to the mongo. However the 'rank' keeps being saved in the db as 'NaN'.

```js
addTask: function (data) {

  var data = data || {};

  data.createdAt = new Date();
  data.status = data.status || null;
  data.owner = Meteor.userId();
  var userID = Meteor.userId();

  // Get the lowest rank for all non-checked tasks
  minRank = Tasks.find({status: null}, {sort: {rank: 1}}).fetch();
  data.rank = minRank.length > 0 ? minRank[0].rank - 1 : 0;

  Tasks.insert(data);
}
```

I've used console.log to confirm data.rank is an number AND I've printed the rank on the page, which flashes briefly as the correct number in the UI before the server catches up to the client and changes it to NaN.

Any ideas?

Comment: `undefined-1` is `NaN` so pretty sure `minRank[0].rank` is `undefined`. What do you get when you log `minRank[0]` and `data` (just before inserting it into the collection)?

Comment: @datacarl - That's the confusing part. Logs show both of those values as the correct number. That's why I'm thinking it must be some difference between server side code and client side code.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Tasks.find() was returning different results on the server than it was on the client.

On the server it was return results for tasks owned by any user, where as the client only returned results owned by the current user because that's all it had access to.

In my case, the lowest-ranked result on the server side had no rank, so it came back as NaN.